# echo results from a SELECT query from a function thats in another file

Tags: php, mysql, function

First time asking on here so please bear with. I apologise if this questions is asked elsewhere, if so please link the answer.

I have two files, one called profile.php and another called functions.php, the functions file is linked and works fine.

My question is / is it possible to return the results as an array from functions.php and use them in profiles.php and how to do so. I've looked high and low and have probably read the answer but failed to understand it.

```
//functions.php
function playerSQL($memberid) {
if (isset($memberid)) {
    global $connect_db;
    $playerSQL = "SELECT memberID AS memberID, membershipType AS membershipType, firstName AS firstName, lastName AS lastName, DOB AS DOB, profileImage AS profileImage, shortBio AS shortBio, background AS background, battingStyle AS battingStyle, bowlingStyle AS bowlingStyle, playCricketID AS playCricketID, sponsor.sponsorImage AS personalSponsor, sponsor.sponsorURL AS personalSponsorURL FROM members LEFT JOIN sponsors AS sponsor ON (sponsor.sponsorID = members.personalSponsor) WHERE memberID = " . $memberid;
    print_r($playerSQL); // Check sql is correct
    $result = mysqli_query($connect_db,$playerSQL);

       $player = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);)
// print_f works from here and returns as expected
       printf ("%s %s\n",$player["lastName"],$player["firstName"]);
}// CLOSE IF 
} // CLOSE FUNC
```

This prints the last name and first name correctly when the function is called.

```
// profile.php
require_once('includes/dbfixtures_conn.php');
include_once('includes/functions.php');

if (isset($_GET['mid'])) {
    $memberid = (int)$_GET['mid'];
}

playerSQL($memberid);
echo 'The Members first name is ' . $player['firstName'];
echo 'The Members last name is ' . $player['lastName'];
```

Is it / how is it possible to use like this.

Comment: use return in your function.php and print in profile.php file @samtruss

Comment: also, try to save it in `$player` before accessing the first name and last eg `$player = playerSQL($memberid);` and in function `return $player`

Comment: try to return array of data which you need you can easily use where you called that function.

Comment: Hi all, a lot virtual hugs I'm sending your way! Thank you all so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the data and store in another variable so that you can access it later on

```
function playerSQL($memberid) {
    if (isset($memberid)) {
        global $connect_db;
        $playerSQL = "SELECT memberID AS memberID, membershipType AS membershipType, firstName AS firstName, lastName AS lastName, DOB AS DOB, profileImage AS profileImage, shortBio AS shortBio, background AS background, battingStyle AS battingStyle, bowlingStyle AS bowlingStyle, playCricketID AS playCricketID, sponsor.sponsorImage AS personalSponsor, sponsor.sponsorURL AS personalSponsorURL FROM members LEFT JOIN sponsors AS sponsor ON (sponsor.sponsorID = members.personalSponsor) WHERE memberID = " . $memberid;
        print_r($playerSQL); 
        $result = mysqli_query($connect_db,$playerSQL); // resolved syntax error

        $player = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        return $player; // returned data

    }
}
$player = playerSQL($memberid);

if ($player) { // check whether data is present or not  
    echo 'The Members first name is ' . $player['firstName'];
    echo 'The Members last name is ' . $player['lastName']; 
}
else {
    echo 'no data available';
}
```

Also, you had syntax error on line:

```
$player = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printf in function use return.

ex: return $player;

in your profile.php file update the function call and return variable as mentioned below.

```
$urvariable_name=playerSQL($memberid);
echo 'The Members first name is ' . $urvariable_name['firstName'];
echo 'The Members last name is ' . $urvariable_name['lastName'];
```